# Pandas to_excel has no data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas.excelwriter

I have issue with my code, and not sure what goes wrong.

The background of my issue:

- I use pandas to query the data from the web for share price (multiple stocks).
- Then, export the data into existing excel file.
- The data frame indeed has data.
- But, the file has no data after completion (I use both ExcelWriter and itertuples, but not successful).

Please help, much appreciated.Please see code below:

```
wb = op.load_workbook(file_location)
full_path = os.path.abspath(file_location)

for stock in stocklist:
   if stock in avail_sheets:
      #Delete existing tabs for having fresh start.
      wb.remove(wb[stock])   

   wb.create_sheet(stock)
   symbol = stock+".AX"  #to specify ASX stock
   url = get_url(symbol, start_date, end_date)

   stock_data = pd.read_csv(url)
   writer = pd.ExcelWriter(full_path)
   stock_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name =stock ,index = False, header = True)
   writer.save()

   # current_sheet = wb[stock]
   # for row in stock_data.itertuples(index=False):
   #     current_sheet.append(row)

wb.save(file_location)
```

Answer (score 0):

as per pandas documentation [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html)

you should use context manager when using **ExcelWriter** object specially if you want to save to multiple sheets and you have to specify the ***mode*** for writing the file :

1. 'a' = append.
2. 'r' = read.
3. 'w' = write.

,if only one sheet just pass the output.xlsx file to the .to_excel() method and specify the sheet name.

```
`
 # for single sheet
 stock_data.to_excel('output.xlsx', sheet_name=stock, index=False, header=True)

 # for multiple sheets or even single sheet
 with pd.ExcelWriter('output.xlsx', mode='a') as writer:
      stock_data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=stock, index=False, header=True)
`
```